# Setting git submodule timeout in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins install that has been working solid for quite a while. Recently it had a problem where one git repository would timeout when pulling submodules.  I started looking for a solution and found that the [Git Client Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin) added support for a submodule timeout value in version 1.9.0 ([issue](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)).  Looking at the [code changeset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bycBU.png), it looks like this should add a timeout field in the submodule options section of the configuration.

Based upon this, I updated Jenkins and all plugins.  (Jenkins 1.581, Git Plugin 2.2.6, Git Client Plugin 1.10.2).  After fixing a couple of issues where credentials didn't migrate, etc I have Jenkins up and running again as it was before the update.

Unfortunately I can't find the submodule timeout option in the settings for Git on a job.  I tried removing the Git settings for a job and even tried creating a new job from scratch, but I can't find any place in the UI to set the options for submodule.  This is what the screen looks like for me:

[image: settings screenshot]

Any ideas or something obvious I am missing?